# Reading textfile in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following textfile which I would like to read:

```
                   MSC.Patran 21.1.348049 Fri Jul 03 23:12:17 PDT 2015 - Analysis Code: MSC.Nastran 

                                         Load Case: Combined_Loads, Subcase 6 

                                         Result Stress Tensor,  - Layer At Z1 

                                                 Entity: Element Tensor


-Entity ID---X Location----Y Location----Z Location----von Mises---
       1     1991.444702    130.527390  -39875.00000     33.643795
       2     1957.370850    389.345581  -39875.00000     27.044231
       3     1889.805542    641.501831  -39875.00000     35.676849
```

I would like to have the results in an array as follows:

```
[[x location,y location, z location, von mises],[...]]]
```

I tried doing this as follows:

```
file = open(“md90test.txt”, “r”) 
print file.read()
```

This doesn't give me any results, how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't give me any results"?

Comment: also `file` is a protected name that you should avoid using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using smart quotes **“ ”**. Use straight quotes instead. Try:

```
f = open("md90test.txt", "r") 
print f.read()
```

Comment: @aeengineer Turn off the "smart quotes" feature in your editor when editing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to parse and get the result

Assume your data is stored in file `vonMises.txt` and has 11 lines of header, you can get the result with these two instructions:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('vonMises.txt', skip_header=11)[:,1:]
```